# 'login' registered, but provider not found, ERRORS in Keycloak

Tags: events, keycloak

I have Keycloak running but the file /opt/keycloak/standalone/log/server.log contains lots of errors:

2020-09-23 13:33:09,184 ERROR [org.keycloak.events.EventBuilder] (default task-684) Event listener 'identity_provider_first_login' registered, but provider not found

2020-09-23 13:33:09,184 ERROR [org.keycloak.events.EventBuilder] (default task-684) Event listener 'login' registered, but provider not found

However, while the login-procedure with 2FA works as expected, I am not happy with it; it are no WARNINGS but real ERRORS.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.